# Azure B2C enabling diagnostic logs to integrate with log analytics asking for subscription, even though tenant is already liked with a subscription

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to integrate B2C with Azure log analytics. Based on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs  logs will be written to Azure active directory.

When I clicked on B2C Tenant, Active directory, diagnostic logs, Seeing a message that no subscription is there. Just a link to create new azure subscription.

In my default tenant I have visual studio enterprise subscription and I was able to link AD to log analytics and retrieve logs.

My B2C tenant is already linked with the same subscription and working as expected.

Is there any other step I need to take for my existing subscription to show in B2C Tenant?

Comment: When you navigate to Azure AD B2C tenant, can you see your active subscription there? https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tKEc.png   If the status of your subscription is not available, you will also be asked for link a new subscription.

Comment: Yes, I already linked subscription. B2C tenant status is showing as registered and subscription ID is showing my visual studio enterprise subscription ID.

Comment: I have the same problem. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs#accessing-audit-logs-through-the-azure-ad-reporting-api), "Audit logs are published to the same pipeline as other activities for Azure Active Directory, so they can be accessed through the Azure Active Directory reporting API." That doesn't seem to include support for all the built-in integration with Azure Monitor/Log Analytics, etc., but (as always) it's hard to tell where the lines are between AAD & AAD B2C.